# how to enable command line navigation shortcuts in fish shell running in iTerm on Mac

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, shell, fish

Setup: MacOs Mojave, iTerm, Fish shell 3.0.2, using fisher have theme bob-the-fish installed as well.

**Would like to be able to use command line navigation keyboard** shortcuts such as ctrl-A to get t the beginning of the line. But it is not happening.

**Further complication** ctrl-U works to delete the line that is before the cursor. but ctrl-A does not work.

I ran fish_key_reader based on an Internet post. And this is the outcome.

for ctrl-U

```
fish_key_reader                                 


hex:   15  char: \cU
bind \cU 'do something'
```

for ctrl-A

```
hex:    1  char: \cA
bind \cA 'do something'
```

Any clues as to how make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you flag a moderator to move this Q to stackoverflow. There are more fish people there.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for your observation! The answer from Zanchey worked. But will keep in mind for any future questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [fish vi key bindings enabled](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#vi-mode-commands), but Ctrl-A is only defined in the [fish emacs key bindings](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#emacs-mode-commands). [Ctrl-U is defined for both styles](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#shared-bindings).

To make Ctrl-A work, you can either switch back to the default emacs key bindings with `fish_default_key_bindings`, or you can add a `bind` invocation to your `config.fish`:

```
bind \ca beginning-of-line
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked! Will read more about these bindings in general. And thank you for the links as well.